# GCP EventArc trigger for Firestore doc creation limited to specific collection?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, event-arc

I see in the GCP console that I can now create EventArc triggers on Firestore document creation using the method `google.firestore.v1.Firestore.CreateDocument` but how do I filter to only documents of a specific collection?

I assume I need to provide a 'Resource name' but I'm unclear what this should be and can't find any documentation about it. Anyone have any ideas?

My project name is `ocapp` and the collection I'm wanting triggers for is `account`.

Comment: I tried on my side, but impossible to get an event. On one or all the colections. I don't know what I am miss

Comment: I can't receive any firestore events on a cloud run service as well, no matter what I try.

Comment: Did anybody succeed?

Answer (score 1):

To trigger on Firestore events, you can use the Audit Log type and filter for Firestore.

Supported methods for Firestore Audit Logs can be found in https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloudevents/blob/main/AUDIT_CATALOG.md#cloud-firestore

```sh
gcloud eventarc triggers create firestore-trigger \
   --destination-run-service=helloworld-firestore \
   --destination-run-region=us-central1 \
   --event-filters="type=google.cloud.audit.log.v1.written" \
   --event-filters="serviceName=firestore.googleapis.com" \
   --event-filters="methodName=google.firestore.v1.Firestore.Write" \
   --service-account=sample-service-account@PROJECT_ID.iam.gserviceaccount.com
```

The following tutorials show how to configure an Eventarc trigger for an Audit Log and consume the audit log event:

- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/2nd-gen/getting-started#audit_logging
- https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/run/cal

Comment: I tried this, but it will listen to everything, not just a specific collection.

Comment: Eventarc just launched direct support for Firestore that supports watching a specific database and path. See https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/eventarc